# Check if any of array hash objects has needed value

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this:

```
arr = [{id: 1, name: 'John' }, {id: 2, name: 'Sam' }, {id: 3, name: 'Bob' }]
```

I need to check if any of `arr` objects have name `Sam`. What is the most elegant way? I can only think of cycling with `each`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ***I need to check if any of arr objects have name Sam***

[`Enumerable#any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) is a good way to go.

```
arr = [ {id: 1, name: 'John' }, {id: 2, name: 'Sam' }, {id: 3, name: 'Bob' }]
arr.any? {|h| h[:name] == "Sam"}
# => true
```

Now if you also want to see which `Array` object has the value *Sam* in it,you can use [`Enumerable#find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) for the same:

```
arr.find {|h| h[:name] == "Sam"}
# => {:id=>2, :name=>"Sam"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also choose **select** or **count** methods

**[Enumberable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)**

```
> arr = [{id: 1, name: 'John' }, {id: 2, name: 'Sam' }, {id: 3, name: 'Bob' }]
> arr.select { | h | h[:name] == 'Sam' }
# => [{:id=>2, :name=>"Sam"}]
```

**[Enumberable#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count)**

```
> arr.count { | h | h[:name] == 'Sam' }
# => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enumberable#find_all](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all) to return all object that match the constrain

```
arr = [{:id=>1,:first_name=>'sam'},{:id=>2,:first_name=>'sam'},{:id=>3,:first_name=>'samanderson'},{:id=>4,:first_name=>'samuel'}]
arr.find_all{|obj| obj.first_name == 'sam'}
# => [{:id=>1,:first_name=>'sam'},{:id=>2,:first_name=>'sam'}]
```